# C++ drawing binary tree in console problems

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I am working on an assignment where I need to create a binary tree. I have the binary logic correct but I am stumped on how and where to create the tree. The screenshot below is my current output that I would like to make into the form of a tree with the root at the top and go down. At this point if going horizontal will be easier I will even settle for that at this point.

[image: C++ binary tree current output]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TreeNode
{
public:
   void insert_node(TreeNode* new_node);
   void print_nodes() const;
   bool find(string value) const;
private:
   string data;
   TreeNode* left;
   TreeNode* right;
friend class BinarySearchTree;
};

class BinarySearchTree
{
public:
   BinarySearchTree();
   void insert(string data);
   void erase(string data);
   int count(string data) const;
   void print() const;
private:
   TreeNode* root;
};

/*
    BinarySearchTree Default constructor
*/

BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree()
{  
   root = NULL;
}

void BinarySearchTree::print() const
{  
   if (root != NULL)
   {
      root->print_nodes();
   }
}

void BinarySearchTree::insert(string data)
{  
    // Creates a new node and sets values
   TreeNode* new_node = new TreeNode;
   // Saves data to new_node and pointers to NULL
   new_node->data = data;
   new_node->left = NULL;
   new_node->right = NULL;
   // sets root as node saved above
   if (root == NULL) 
   {
       root = new_node;
   }
    /*
        If root has has been set then determine how to link new_node.
        root is the parent node and new_node will be the child of root
    */
   else root->insert_node(new_node);
}

void TreeNode::insert_node(TreeNode* new_node)
{  
   // this-> referrs to root node
   if (new_node->data < this->data)
   {  
       // Sets left node of root to
      // point to new_node
      if (this->left == NULL) 
          {
              this->left = new_node;
          }
      // inserts a new node onto root->left
      else this->left->insert_node(new_node);
   }
   else if (this->data < new_node->data)
   {  
      if (this->right == NULL) 
          {
              // inserts a new node onto root->right
              this->right = new_node;  

           }
      else this->right->insert_node(new_node);
   }
}

int BinarySearchTree::count(string data) const
{
   if (root == NULL) return 0;
   else if (root->find(data)) return 1;
   else return 0;
}

void BinarySearchTree::erase(string data)
{
   // Find node to be removed

   TreeNode* to_be_removed = root;
   TreeNode* parent = NULL;
   bool found = false;
   while (!found && to_be_removed != NULL)
   {
      if (to_be_removed->data < data)
      {
         parent = to_be_removed;
         to_be_removed = to_be_removed->right;
      }
      else if (data < to_be_removed->data)
      {
         parent = to_be_removed;
         to_be_removed = to_be_removed->left;
      }
      else found = true;
   }

   if (!found) return;

   // to_be_removed contains data

   // If one of the children is empty, use the other

   if (to_be_removed->left == NULL || to_be_removed->right == NULL)
   {
      TreeNode* new_child;
      if (to_be_removed->left == NULL) 
         new_child = to_be_removed->right;
      else 
         new_child = to_be_removed->left;
       if (parent == NULL) // Found in root
         root = new_child;
      else if (parent->left == to_be_removed)
         parent->left = new_child;
      else 
         parent->right = new_child;
      return;
   }

   // Neither subtree is empty

   // Find smallest element of the right subtree

   TreeNode* smallest_parent = to_be_removed;
   TreeNode* smallest = to_be_removed->right;
   while (smallest->left != NULL)
   {
      smallest_parent = smallest;
      smallest = smallest->left;
   }

   // smallest contains smallest child in right subtree

   // Move contents, unlink child
   to_be_removed->data = smallest->data;
   if (smallest_parent == to_be_removed) 
      smallest_parent->right = smallest->right; 
   else 
      smallest_parent->left = smallest->right; 
}

bool TreeNode::find(string value) const
{
   if (value < data)
   {
      if (left == NULL) return false;
      else return left->find(value);
   }
   else if (data < value)
   {
      if (right == NULL) return false;
      else return right->find(value);
   }
   else 
      return true;
}

void TreeNode::print_nodes() const
{ 

   if (this->right != NULL)
   {
       cout << data << "\n" << "\\" << "\n"  <<  this->right->data << " " << "\n";
       this->right->print_nodes();


        if (this->left != NULL) 
        {
            cout <<  data << "\n" << "/" << "\n" << this->left->data << "\n";
            this->left->print_nodes();
        }
   }

}

int main()
{  
   BinarySearchTree t;
   t.insert("D");
   t.insert("B");
   t.insert("A");
   t.insert("C");
   t.insert("F");
   t.insert("E");
   t.insert("I");
   t.insert("G");
   t.insert("H");
   t.insert("J");

   t.print();

   cout << "\n \n";

   cout << "\n \n";

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here is one:

```
A
|-B
| |-C
| | |-H
| | `-I
| `-D
|   |-F
|   `-G
`-E
```

Here A has children B and E.  B has C and D.  Etc...

So how can we pull this off?  Here is pseudocode:

```
Let S = {} (an empty global set of integers)

procedure indent(level)
for i in [0..level) 
  if i \in S print "| "
  else print "  "

procedure tee(level)
indent(level)
print("|-")
S = S + { level }

procedure ell(level)
indent(level)
print("`-")
S = S - { level }

procedure print(node, level)
if node is null
  print("[null]" with newline) // only prints when 1 child is missing
else
  print(node label with newline)
  if node has any children
    tee(level)
    print(node.left, level + 1)
    ell(level)
    print(node.right, level + 1)
```

The set tracks which columns need the vertical bars.  Every "tee" shape starts a vertical bar.  Every "ell" shape ends one in the same column.

The set can be an array of booleans (characters), initially made empty by being set all zero.  The rest is pretty much a line-for-line translation to C.

My quick results on a complete tree of 31 nodes.

```
L0
|-L1
| |-L2
| | |-L3
| | | |-L4
| | | `-L5
| | `-L6
| |   |-L7
| |   `-L8
| `-L9
|   |-L10
|   | |-L11
|   | `-L12
|   `-L13
|     |-L14
|     `-L15
`-L16
  |-L17
  | |-L18
  | | |-L19
  | | `-L20
  | `-L21
  |   |-L22
  |   `-L23
  `-L24
    |-L25
    | |-L26
    | `-L27
    `-L28
      |-L29
      `-L30
```

For the general audience it's worth pointing out that this works will for N-ary trees with child labels (such as for abstract syntax trees in compilers).  Add a child name parameter to `ell` and `tee` and call `tee` for every child except the last, which remains `ell`.

Answer (score 2):

Without giving you the complete answer(it's an assignment after all) I can point you to some references and search terms. What you want to accomplish is hard with recursion. You might prefer to do a [breadth first traversal](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/).

You basically use another container to add nodes in right to left order by level within your tree. Once it's done, you iterate on that second container and print the values. Since you can count the number of levels, it will be easy to format the output with spaces to indent the left and right nodes.

It can also be done in a single traversal(still using a second container) but the algorithm is a little more complex.